# Will changing my Apple ID affect any apps that I have purchased?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I want to change my Apple ID, simply just because I don't want to use that name or that email address anymore.  Will it affect any apps that I have purchased in the past with that old Apple ID? If I have deleted one of those apps that I purchased, will I have to repurchase that app again with the new Apple ID?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Apple ID that ends with `mac.com` or `me.com` then you probably can't, otherwise this [FAQ covers how to change your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE40).

1. Go to http://appleid.apple.com/
2. Click **"Manager your Account"**
3. Login to your account
4. Click on the **"Name, ID, and Email Address"** option on the left
5. Next to **Apple ID** click the Edit button and fill out your new details.

Purchases are bound to your account, so short of deleting your account you should be fine. (In fact you can still access old purchases by logging into the relevant store with your old account according to the **[FAQ about Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE37)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have a @mac.com or @me.com apple ID.  Those can cause problems, and cannot be changed.

If not, I think you can change your email and name for your apple Id.

Apple has support directions in [KB HE40](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE40) and an Apple ID FAQ in [KB HE37](http://support.apple.com/kb/he37).

> **How do I change my Apple ID Name or personal information?**
>
> You can change your Apple ID Name at My Apple ID. Select your country and language, enter your desired changes, then click the Continue button. Changes take effect immediately. You can also use My Apple ID to change your personal information, such as your mailing address or email address. See How to change the name you use for your Apple ID if you'd like more information.